# How do I actually remember the address pointed by pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers

Working with linked lists, I am doing the following:

```cpp
struct Node {
    int val;
    struct Node* prev;
    struct Node* next;
};


struct Node* head;
struct Node* tail;
struct Node* temp;
```

where Node is a structure for linked list, head points to first element, tail to the last, temp is for intermediate computation.

`move_function(address1, address2)` actually swaps node at addresses 1&2 by suitably changing their prev, next pointers.

```cpp
void move(struct Node* t1, struct Node* t2)  //known that t1->next ..... ->next = t2, move from t2 to t1

{
    cout << "move";

    if (t1->next == t2)
    {
        cout << " Conseq";
        temp1 = t1->prev;
        temp2 = t2->next;

        t1->next = temp2; if (temp2 != NULL) temp2->prev = t1;
        t2->prev = temp1; if (temp1 != NULL) temp1->next = t2;
        t2->next = t1;
        t1->prev = t2;

    }

    else

    {
        cout << "...";

        t2->prev->next = t2->next;

        if (t2->next != NULL) { t2->next->prev = t2->prev; }

        if (t1 != head) { t1->prev->next = t2; t2->prev = t1->prev; t2->next = t1; t1->prev = t2; }

        else { head = t2; t2->prev = NULL; t2->next = t1; t1->prev = t2; }
    }

}
```

```cpp
if (<node to be shifted is the last one i.e. *tail*>)
    
{    
    temp = tail->prev;    
    move_function (head, tail);    
    tail= temp;
    
}
```

It turns out that while writing `temp = tail->prev;` temp retains the definition, and not what I want i.e. the address of the element behind it (which needs to be set as tail after movement). More concretely, in the end, after executing `move_function (head, tail); tail=temp;` contrary to what I want,  for number of elements in list = =2,`tail->prev == NULL is true.` What I really want is to remember my last element after movement.

What is happening here, and how do I work around? While writing, `temp = tail->prev`, if node at *tail* is shifted to *head* position and its *prev* set to NULL, does `temp->prev` become `NULL`?

Thanks!

Comment: What does the `Node` look like? And what is `temp`? Can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 1):

This is why it's a bad idea to declare multiple variables on a single line. The problem is that only `head` is a pointer. I.e. the following two pieces of code are equivalent:

```
// The way you declared the variables:
struct Node* head, tail, temp;

// Above is equivalent to:
struct Node* head;
struct Node tail;
struct Node temp;
```

Simply define each variable on a separate line. It will make the code more readable and fix it at the same time.

Live demo of the issue with your declarations: https://godbolt.org/z/f154dT.

**Edit:** Also, since you're writing C++, not C, there's no reason to put `struct` there. Just use `Node * head;`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I wrote wrongly. I actually declared the way you have suggested

Comment: In that case, please provide a minimal reproducible example so we can actually check what's going on.